# DMM Hack to Log Amps:

Tags: datalogger, instrumentation, data-storage

I have a spare DMM (Digital MultiMeter) that I would like to use to log the displayed data at 1 sample/sec.

What would be the least expensive way to mod the DMM to log the data that appears on the display?

I know that the meter data goes though an AC/DC converter, ADC, decoder, & then to the display.

Comment: Without knowing more about the multimeter, it is pretty difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: It's just a cheapo Cen-tek from Harbor Freight.  It has a blob of epoxy covering the main chip, so there's no way to get the chip id info.  But I did find a url on Instructables to mod the DMM--so today is a good day!  Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 5):

Actually many low cost DMMs are based on ASICs that do have the ability to send their output through an interface to a computer. Yours may be one that has that capability.

See this web site [Unlock Serial Communication on a DMM](https://flashingleds.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/unlocking-rs232-output-from-your-multimeter/)

[or here](http://hackaday.com/2010/11/30/unlocking-rs232-serial-comm-on-a-multimeter/)

Comment: Excellent response!  Neither of your links was to the cheapo meter that I have, but your wording was enough for me to find the exact mod that I am looking for [here!](http://www.instructables.com/id/DMM-Piggyback-add-RS-232/?ALLSTEPS)  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Webcam and OCR is probably your best bet. The meter could be too integrated to extract the signal between the ADC and the display (the ADC and display controller could be integrated on the same chip, so you would either have to interpret the LCD segment drive signals or provide your own ADC). Also, you could run in to serious issues with isolation. Some meters support transmitting readings over RF or IR, but this is uncommon. Might as well just read the display directly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant display controller

Comment: Agreed -- I plan to use an external optoisolator.  I guess the output to the LCD segments will probably binary on multiple pins.  Any thoughts on how that could be read & stored digitally outside the DMM?

Comment: Lcd segments are generally driven with low voltage ac. Also, there will probably be some sort of multiplexing going on. There are also going to be a good handful of electrodes as well, not just the digits but also battery and unit indicators, analog style bargraph, etc. Recreating the display from looking at the segment drives is not a particularly trivial option.

Comment: forencich - Is there a defined protocol for such a data stream?

Comment: There is no defined protocol. It's the display drive for the physical LCD segments, not the interface to a display controller chip. It will depend on the construction of the display itself. Most LCD drivers use low voltage ac to drive the segments, so you would need some reliable way to detect this as well as figure out the multiplexing scheme.

Comment: What's the advantage of driving the segments with LV AC?  Why wouldn't they use DC the distance is very short & the update frequency isn't very high.

Comment: What do you suppose the advantage was in using LV AC to drive the segments when DC would work?

Comment: The segments are designed to be driven with AC, not with DC.  If you drive a segment with DC, it will fade relatively quickly.  It's also possible that the segment will be damaged if it is placed under a DC bias for too long.

Comment: Link with some more information: http://www.goldenviewdisplay.com/driving_LCD_display.html

Comment: Hmm.. interesting.  TY!